# How to split string into component parts in Linux Bash/Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing the second version of my post-receive git hook.

I have a `GL_REPO` variable which conforms to:

```
/project.name/vhost-type/versioncodename
```

It may or may not have a trailing and/or preceding slash.

My current code misunderstood the function of the following code, and as a result it clearly duplicates `$versioncodename` into each variable:

```
# regex out project codename
PROJECT_NAME=${GL_REPO##*/}
echo "project codename is: $PROJECT_NAME"

# extract server target vhost-type -fix required
VHOST_TYPE=${GL_REPO##*/}
echo "server target is: $VHOST_TYPE"

# get server project - fix required
PROJECT_CODENAME=${GL_REPO##*/}
echo "server project is: $PROJECT_CODENAME"
```

What is the correct method for taking these elements one at a time from the back of the string, or guaranteeing that a three part string allocates these variables?

I guess it might be better to split into an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

GL_REPO=/project.name/vhost-type/versioncodename
GL_REPO=${GL_REPO#/} # remove preceding slash, if any

IFS=/ read -a arr <<< "$GL_REPO"

PROJECT_NAME="${arr[0]}"
VHOST_TYPE="${arr[1]}"
PROJECT_CODENAME="${arr[2]}"
```

---

<sup>*UPDATE: an alternative solution by [anishsane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793796/anishsane):*</sup>

```
IFS=/ read PROJECT_NAME VHOST_TYPE PROJECT_CODENAME <<< "$GL_REPO"
```

Comment: I was going to answer exactly this. +1. Clean & simple.

Comment: Alternately `IFS=/ read PROJECT_NAME VHOST_TYPE PROJECT_CODENAME <<< "$GL_REPO"`

Comment: Hi I used your solution in the end

Comment: @anishsane: looks great. I have updated my answer with your solution. user3706702: thanks

Comment: @anishine my thanks was removed from the solution due to editing, so just to be sure I am grateful to everyone who helped including Euginiu Rosca, and several other good solutions to this problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut` with a field separator to pull out items by order:

```
NAME=$(echo $GL_REPO | cut -d / -f 1)
```

You can repeat the same for other fields. The trailing/leading slash you can ignore (you'll get a NAME field being empty, for example) or you can strip off a leading slash with `${GL_REPO##/}` (similarly, you can strip off a trailing slash with `${GL_REPO%%/}`).

Comment: Hi thanks. I used part of your solution in resolving the problem to make sure both ends had the slashes removed

Answer (score 1):

This is another way:

```
GL_REPO="/project.name/vhost-type/versioncodename"
GL_REPO="${GL_REPO/#\//}" 
#^replace preceding slash (if any) with empty string.
IFS="/" arr=($GL_REPO)
echo "PN: ${arr[0]} VHT: ${arr[1]} VC: ${arr[2]}"
```

Using [Bash Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
GL_REPO="/project.name/vhost-type/versioncodename"
patt="([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)"
[[ $GL_REPO =~ $patt ]]
echo "PN: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} VHT: ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} VC: ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```